# How to scrape a hidden hyperlink from a button with Python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the following website for a project: https://www.tunefind.com/show/chicago-fire/season-1/12210
The last step is to scrape the links to the spotify songs mentioned on a page. Normally I look into the source code and it is clear from there.
However, in this case not. Looking into the source around the spotify button I cannot find a hyperlink directing me to the song. Probably done on purpose, to prevent scraping? (Oops)

Is there a way to get the hyperlink from the button? I am aware of an 'internet' interface in Python which clicks on the buttons, but I would rather not use this, as this will affect the load time tremendiously.

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably incidental. The site is built with react, so it hides a lot of its operational data in the virtuall dom. Good luck finding a reliable way to get it out.

Answer (score 0):

You doing it wrong by scraping the site. If they change one single thing your whole project stops working. You should use their API instead. **https://www.tunefind.com/product/api**

Comment: You are right. For now it is a small project, so I it is fine if something changes. Next to that, I do not know anything about how to use API's 

Comment: Basically, you make a request to their server and deal with the response data whichever way you want ... look it up will save you tons of time instead of scrapping it

Comment: Well, that sounds a lot easier indeed haha

Answer (score 0):

If using Chorme, Look at DevTools, go to Network tab an reload the site. You'll find that the data yoou need is in this url:

https://www.tunefind.com/api/frontend/show/chicago-fire/season/1?fields=episodes,theme-song,music-supervisors,hot-songs,top-users,related-questions-season,composers,albums&metatags=1

Comment: Thanks! I found the information inside the link your link. Next step is to get it into python :)

Answer (score 0):

not sure if that helps you, but all that data is loaded up into `window.__INITIAL_STATE__`

Comment: Will look into that!